# Wrapper gs:// not allowed in include

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am trying to includes a file that is stored in Google Storage bucket. However, I get the warning (that leads to error):

```
Warning: include(): gs:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0
```

I have attempted to set allow_url_include (and allow_url_fopen) in my php.ini file and using ini_set but got same results.

Does anyone know if Google is going to allow including files from Google storage (for cache and compiled includes) or if there is a hack? I attempted to use eval() but the compiled source failed even if I removed the opening and closing php tags.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using `file_get_contents()` or the cURL library? Includes from remote websites are not recommended due to security and performance issues.

Comment: I can read the file, but in this case I need to include it. The purpose is that smarty compiles the template files. I cannot write the files locally (unless I'm wrong). So I have to write the compiled files to google storage. However, when smarty goes to include the compiled templates I get the error above.

Comment: have you seen this? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/overview

Comment: Yes. I guess, there is not going to be a way. Google should allow some storage for caching IMO. But oh well, I guess Smarty is a no-go with app engine unless either the gs:// wrapper is added or some local storage is allowed, or some type of mapping to GS in the app.yaml file.

Comment: Also, when I try to register it, it returns "Warning: stream_wrapper_register(): Protocol gs:// is already defined."

Comment: removed, worked locally not once deployed.

Comment: There'll be some news on being able to do this real soon.

Comment: This would be a great feature to request  (and for other people to star) in the GAE issue tracker. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?q=label:Language-PHP&sort=-stars

Comment: Thanks for the info Stuart. Will keep my eye open. Allowing this would open the use of Smarty at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://gaeforphp-blog.appspot.com/2013/06/13/whats-new-for-php-in-the-app-engine-1-8-1-release/) announcement on how you can setup you application to include files from Google Cloud Storage.